# Different types of Groovy execution in Java

Tags: java, scripting, groovy

I have 3 questions regarding using Groovy in java. They are all related together so I'm only creating one question here.

**1)** There are: GroovyClassLoader, GroovyShell, GroovyScriptEngine. But what is the difference between using them?

For example for this code:

```
static void runWithGroovyShell() throws Exception {
    new GroovyShell().parse(new File("test.groovy")).invokeMethod("hello_world", null);
}

static void runWithGroovyClassLoader() throws Exception {
    Class scriptClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(new File("test.groovy"));
    Object scriptInstance = scriptClass.newInstance();
    scriptClass.getDeclaredMethod("hello_world", new Class[]{}).invoke(scriptInstance, new Object[]{});
}

static void runWithGroovyScriptEngine() throws Exception {
    Class scriptClass = new GroovyScriptEngine(".").loadScriptByName("test.groovy");
    Object scriptInstance = scriptClass.newInstance();
    scriptClass.getDeclaredMethod("hello_world", new Class[]{}).invoke(scriptInstance, new Object[]{});
}
```

**2)** What is the best way to load groovy script so it remains in memory in *compiled* form, and then I can call a function in that script when I need to.

**3)** How do I expose my java methods/classes to groovy script so that it can call them when needed?

Comment: updated the answer. You can also cast the GroovyObject to YourInterface and call methods directly.

Comment: @NarendraPathai oh i didn't think of that before. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the link in the answer, found that GroovyScriptEngine indeed uses cache internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods 2 and 3 both return the parsed `class` in return. So you can use a `map` to keep them in memory once they are parsed and successfully loaded.

```
Class scriptClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(new File("test.groovy"));
map.put("test.groovy",scriptClass);
```

**UPDATE:**

[GroovyObject](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html) link to the groovy object docs.

Also this is possible to cast the object directly as GroovyObject and other java classes are indistinguishable.

```
Object aScript = clazz.newInstance();
MyInterface myObject = (MyInterface) aScript;
myObject.interfaceMethod();
 //now here you can also cache the object if you want to
```

Cannot comment on efficiency. But I guess if you keep the loaded classes in memory, one time parsing would not hurt much.

**UPDATE For efficiency**:
You should use `GroovyScriptEngine`, it uses **script caching** internally.

Here is the link: [Groovy Script Engine](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java#L99)

Otherwise you can always test it using some performance benchmarks yourself and you would get rough idea. For example: Compiling groovy scripts with all three methods in three different loops and see which performs better. Try using same and different scripts, to see if caching kicks in, in some way.

**UPDATE FOR PASSING PARAMS TO AND FROM SCRIPT**
[Binding class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) will help you sending the params to and from the script.

[Example Link](http://programmingitch.blogspot.in/2012/01/passing-parameters-into-groovy-script.html)

```
// setup binding
def binding = new Binding()
binding.a = 1
binding.setVariable('b', 2)
binding.c = 3
println binding.variables

// setup to capture standard out
def content = new StringWriter()
binding.out = new PrintWriter(content)

// evaluate the script
def ret = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate('''
def c = 9
println 'a='+a
println 'b='+b
println 'c='+c 
retVal = a+b+c
a=3
b=2
c=1
''')

// validate the values
assert binding.a == 3
assert binding.getVariable('b') == 2
assert binding.c == 3 // binding does NOT apply to def'd variable
assert binding.retVal == 12 // local def of c applied NOT the binding!

println 'retVal='+binding.retVal
println binding.variables
println content.toString()
```

Comment: Hm, thank you. That answers my first two questions, but by any chance do you know anything about 3? PS - sorry if I'm asking too much...

Comment: you mean you want to send some objects in script to use them in the script?

Comment: Well, for example I have a java class that runs groovy scripts. And inside that class there is some function that I want to expose to groovy. So, inside a groovy script I can call that java function.

Comment: Check out the links and the example given above. Shows how to pass params to the script.

Comment: So if you want to use the methods of the Java class you will have to pass it in the binding to the script and then use the function ther.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work like that with methods. In groovy you can just use import, and import any of your java packages. But that's the problem, I don't want users of my app to be able to use all methods, instead I would like to expose only a few of the methods that I choose. But well, I guess I will figure it out later. Thank you for your indepth reply!

Comment: There are method pointers in Groovy. May be you could use them. But I have not used them this way till now. I have restricted using the `interface`.